# Show Table Data in Visual Studio from SQL CE Database

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I am trying to show the table data of a table in a SQL CE database through Visual Studio and for some reason I'm getting the following error.

Now, here is a brief recent history of this machine and I'll give it as best I can.  Most recently I repaired the Visual Studio SP1 installation in hopes that it would fix this problem.  Prior to that I installed SQL 2012 due to a requirement surrounding integration tests so I now have SQL 2008 and SQL 2012 installed on this box.  Some other items of interest might be that I have LightSwitch installed and I had at one time installed Visual Studio 2012 RC - but have since uninstalled it.

I'm hoping that I can just repair something and get it working :)

I look forward to your responses.

[image: Visual Studio Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently a number of things could have caused this - but in my case I believe it was installing SQL Server 2012 on my box. Follow these steps and you'll be good to go if you're getting this error.

1. Navigate in Windows Explorer to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Visual Database Tools`.
2. Rename the file `dsref80.dll` to `dsref80.dll.old`.
3. Repair the Visual Studio 2010 installation (the original root one).
4. Reboot your machine.

And boom! It's fixed.

Word to the wise - consider just using virtual machines - period. Different types of projects require different types of installations which always step on each other - it's just safer to use virtual machines for every possible configuration these days it seems.

In short, because of the complexities of todays software requirements, just build yourself a local development network out of virtual machines and turn your box into a host.